# How to make ball bounce vertically only and not horizontally using SKSpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am making an iOS application in which I only want the ball to bounce up & down, not horizontally or by any other angle. Unfortunately, the way I decided to design the game led to some problems down the road. Here is a GIF that kind of shows what my problem is:

[image]

Basically: sometimes when I click to rotate the pentagon, it hits the ball at an angle when I only want it going up and down.

Here is my code for the ball:

```
func createBallNode(ballColor: String) -> SKSpriteNode {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: ballColor)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame)+1)

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.99
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0

    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Rect.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Rect.rawValue

    return ball
}
```

Is there anyway I can design the ball to always move in a certain line (vertically)? Does anyone have design suggestions for the ball, or maybe a different way of moving it (SKActions, ex: moveTo rather than using gravity).

Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You can restrict the x-coordinate of a node with the `positionX` `SKConstraint`. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKConstraint/positionX:)

Comment: @0x141E so how would I go about using that function for my scenario? I can't seem to get it right....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict a node's x-coordinate to a fixed value, define an `SKRange` with the minimum and maximum parameters set to the same value.

```
let centerX = ball.position.x
let range = SKRange(lowerLimit:centerX, upperLimit:centerX)
```

From the range, define a `positionX` constraint

```
let constraint = SKConstraint.positionX(range)
```

Lastly, add the constraint to node's `constraints` array

```
ball.constraints = [constraint]
```

This should work with your existing code if you add it above the `return ball` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The ball bounces irregularly because when you are moving the sides of the pentagon, the ball touches a tiny little bit of side and changes its trajectory. That's how gravity works.

If you want to bounce the ball *your way*, use `SKAction`s like this:

```
    let up = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 40), duration: 0.3)
    let down = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -40), duration: 0.3)
    let upAndDown = SKAction.sequence([up, down])
    let foreverUpDown = SKAction.repeatActionForever(upAndDown)
```

And just call `runAction` on the ball.

Comment: Yeah, definitely no need for realistic physics simulation here. It can even hurt obviously. Contact detection is still needed though (which works fine with SKActions and is legit way to use these two in combination).

Comment: What aspects of my current code do I need to replace with this? all of the middle "physicsBody" stuff?

Comment: @JimmyLee You need to apply this action to move a ball up and down. You have to set collisionBitMask to 0. Then you have to define contactTestBit mask to detect unallowed contacts. And that's it.

Comment: Also you have to make a ball unaffected by gravity. No need for realistic physics simulation. You only want to use contact detection part.

Comment: @Whirlwind okay, I did this however I'm still able to hit it at an angle and cause it to not bounce vertically...

Can I force it to never move horizontal even on collision with another node?

Comment: @JimmyLee You should disable all collisions. Means no collisions between other objects and a ball. ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0, plus modify collision bit masks on other bodies so they can't collide with a ball.

Comment: @Whirlwind But if I set ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0, then the ball just goes right through the rectangle, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: @JimmyLee Define dy parameter of an action in such way so it can't go through ;)